# Wordpress and JQuery: Unable to use jquery load function for ajax calling

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Im creating a custom theme. I need to run some ajax in my theme but i don't know ajax very well. I only know how to use jquery load() funcion to do server side tasks. But problem is when i use load() function in my jquery it doesn't work in wordpress.

Here's my function.php file:

```
function footerfunction() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'footerfunction');
```

Here's my scripts.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.button1').live('click', function(){
        $(".div1").load("contents.php");
       });
});
```

Here the codes from contents.php file doesn't load into class=div1. Any solution?

N.B: scripts.js and contents.php both files located in same directory.

Comment: live has been deprecated and removed !

Comment: @kowsar89 - Apart from comment from @adeneo, provide the path to `comments.php` file. WordPress, after render a page, will look for the resources w.r.t. to the domain root.

Answer (score 1):

Re-adjust your script file as per below, Included comments to describe changes where necessary.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    /**
     *   Re-adjusted to .on('click')
     *   Future-proof any DOM changes with
     *   $(document).
    **/
    $(document).on('click', '.button1', function() {
         /**
          *  Use a slightly more un-relative path.
          *  to load your contents.php.
         **/
         $(".div1").load("wp-content/themes/yourtheme/contents.php");
    });
});
```

If you're still having trouble, it would be best to include any JavaScript errors from the JavaScript console, most commonly `F12` on the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks a lot MackieeE, your code works after i remove "/" before "wp-content". I modified it to $(".div1").load("wp-content/themes/yourtheme/contents.php"); and then it works

Comment: Ah awesome, I'll edit the answer so peeps in the future don't have to make the same mistake, thanks for notifying :-)

Comment: also, apologies for reminding, if you think it answered your question - please accept!